# What library does the arg "-lphp5" refer to for GCC?

Tags: php, compile, gcc

Where can I get the library -lphp5 refers to?  Is it a part of a metapackage for YUM?

Can I find the source somewhere?  I'm having some configuration issues with PHC and this seems to be at the root of them.

Answer (score 2):

On an overview level, it means link with the php5 library.  If PHC is this: http://www.phpcompiler.org then it makes sense that it would be looking for the PHP lib.  Where is this installed on your machine?  You should be able to do: `locate libphp5` and find it.  If locate doesn't see it, you need to install PHP.

On a more specific level, `-l` means to look for a library.  `-lNAME` will make the linker look for `libNAME.so` first, and then if it can't find it, try `libNAME.a`.  Where will it look?  Generally `/usr/lib`, `/lib`, some compiler specific directories, and any directories provided with `-L`.  How can you make PHC find it if it isn't in a common path?  You should be able to set something in the build script for PHC.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting this when installing PHP5.

From [PHP5 Install Problems - libphp5.so not created](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-23665.html) :

> When compiling you are receiving the
>   message that the libphp5.so is not
>   found, you must configure with the
>   following option:
>
> ./configure
>   --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs
>
> You'll see immediately when compiling
>   with "make install" that the library
>   will be created.

If that's the case, why don't you install a binary release of PHP5, instead of compiling it from the sources?

Comment: When compiling for phc, you generally need `--enable-embed` too.